# changing values in a matrix using an if function

Tags: r

I have a matrix comprised of elements and their ratings e.g.

```
matrix(data=c("A","B","C",NA,0.7,0.5,0,NA,"D","E","F","G",0.9,0.4,0.2,0.005),nrow=4,byrow=FALSE)

    [,1] [,2]  [,3] [,4]   
[1,] "A"  "0.7" "D"  "0.9"  
[2,] "B"  "0.5" "E"  "0.4"  
[3,] "C"  "0"   "F"  "0.2"  
[4,] NA   NA    "G"  "0.005"
```

I would like to replace all the ratings (and the elements next to them) which are less than 0.1 with NA.

e.g.

```
matrix(data=c("A","B",NA,NA,0.7,0.5,NA,NA,"D","E","F",NA,0.9,0.4,0.2,NA),nrow=4, byrow=FALSE)

    [,1] [,2]  [,3] [,4]  
[1,] "A"  "0.7" "D"  "0.9"  
[2,] "B"  "0.5" "E"  "0.4"  
[3,] NA   NA    "F"  "0.2"  
[4,] NA   NA    NA   NA
```

I was about to do this in a large for loop when I thought there must be a better way. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and precise what you mean by and "the elements next to them". It sounds like the element just before in the same row . isn'it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example 'C' goes to NA. I presume this is a mistake so I've not replicated it.

```
mat <- matrix(data=c("A","B","C",NA,0.7,0.5,0,NA,"D","E","F","G",0.9,0.4,0.2,0.005),nrow=4,byrow=FALSE)
mat[mat < 0.1] <- NA
```

Furthermore, if you are truly storing elements and their ratings, perhaps a data.frame would be a better choice:

```
> data.frame(element=toupper(letters[1:7]), rating=c(0.7,0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.2,0.005))
   element  rating
1        A   0.700
2        B   0.500
3        C   0.000
4        D   0.900
5        E   0.400
6        F   0.200
7        G   0.005
```

You could then make these values, and their entire row, NA with:

```
> df[df[,"rating"] < 0.1,] <- NA
> df
  element rating
1       A    0.7
2       B    0.5
3    <NA>     NA
4       D    0.9
5       E    0.4
6       F    0.2
7    <NA>     NA
```

Finally, here's how to transform your matrix to a data.frame

```
elements <- as.vector(mat[,seq(from=1, to=ncol(mat),by=2)])
ratings <- as.vector(mat[,seq(from=2, to=ncol(mat),by=2)])
df <- data.frame(element=elements,rating=ratings)
```

Comment: Thank you for the very fast response. Unfortunatly I do need the character in the adjacent (left) column to turn to NA if the value is below 0.1. Therefore C and G in the above example should turn to NA.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the data.frame suggestion part of my answer to accomplish this. I'm not sure off the top of my head how to do it with your matrix. Is there a reason you need your data in this odd matrix format?

Comment: I think most of us would agree that storing data like this in a data.frame or a couple of arrays makes a lot more sense than this matrix format.

Comment: The only reason for the matrix form is that it is from code I inherited. I need to find time to go through and improve the code. Thanks, your answers are very helpful.

Comment: Ok, good luck. For now I've added a couple of lines which transform your current matrix into a data.frame for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am agrre with others. It is preferable to use matrix for numeric, and data.frame for different tpes columns.

You don't precise what do you means by the elements next to the element < 0.1, but in understand from your comments character in the adjacent (left).

Here my solution. I transform your matrix to a vector for simple indexing,  than I transform it again to a matrix.

```
mat <- matrix(data=c("A","B","C", NA,
                     0.7,0.5,0,NA,
                     "D","E","F","G",
                     0.9,0.4,0.2,0.005),
                     nrow=4,byrow=FALSE)
dim(mat) <- NULL
mat[c(which(mat<0.1)-4,which(mat<0.1))] <- NA
matrix(mat,nrow=4,byrow=F)

   [,1] [,2]  [,3] [,4] 
[1,] "A"  "0.7" "D"  "0.9"
[2,] "B"  "0.5" "E"  "0.4"
[3,] NA   NA    "F"  "0.2"
[4,] NA   NA    NA   NA
```